Does it matter which sheet pan I use for cooking french fries in the oven?
Wondering if my dark circle sheet pan is better for French fries vs 11x7 baking sheet pan.

Maybe, maybe not. All my rectangular pans with edges on them warp rather dramatically when heated, sometimes violently enough to toss small items off (but usually not that hard.) Doesn't seem to happen with the round pan with edges. Not doing that is one point in favor of edgeless sheets, but there are other points against them.
Potatoes are inexpensive. Put some fries on each sheet, try them in your oven, see which makes "baked fries" better or if there's no difference worth caring about, in your opinion. Carry on from there based on your results.

Note that if you put fries on different layers in the oven at once, the lower levels will get less heat and turn out slightly different than they would have with empty layers above them.

It cooks differently, but I don’t know about ‘less heat’.  They lower pan will heat up more so the bits in contact with the lower ban will brown more than the upper tray… while the top will get more radiant heat and so the tops will brown more than the lower tray.

Depending on how absurd you want to get on running down small (if any) differences, you can do each sheet individually, swap them halfway through cooking, swap them every 5 minutes. I have a guess as to what the result will be, (or I know what my result was, for my taste) but I'd rather that Jenna carry out the experiment and post the results as an answer, ideally with pictures.

There are three potential considerations:

Total surface area: food will brown faster when it isn’t as densely packed. Also, too large of a pan for your oven will prevent air from flowing around the pan, which can keep food from cooking evenly
Color of the pan: light, shiny pans will reflect more radiant heat than dark, dull pans.  This means that darker pans will heat up more and so the food in contact with it will brown a little bit faster
Size of any lip: this both blocks some radiant heat, but can also hold in moisture as it evaporates, which will slow down the browning a bit.

(If you have one of the perforated pans for crisping up pizza or whatever, the evaporation and oversized pan issues shouldn’t be a problem)
